# Please reconfigure JavaFX Scene Builder Path Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml, scenebuilder

It looks like it's possible to view the SceneBuilder inside Intellij. I would like to do that but I always get this error:

[image: Intellij SceneBuilder error]

I have already set the correct path. At least I can open the `.fxml` files with right click -> Open in SceneBuilder. Furthermore it's not even possible to click on the blue path.

Is this a bug or is it even possible to view the SceneBuilder inside Intellij?

I am on Linux with Intellij Ultimate 14.1.4, OpenJDK 8u51, SceneBuilder 8u60_b26, OpenJFX 8u45

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No I did not solve this as far as I remember.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the solution to this is quite easy.

Go to the settings menu of IntelliJ and look for the following : Applications & Frameworks > JavaFX

There you can enter the path to the scene builder executable, which is commonly : ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe***

IMAGE:
[configure scenebuilder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGUkD.png)